# Clear pending builds with TeamCity UI

Tags: teamcity

In the last step of a TeamCity (10.0.4) build chain a couple of pending builds failed to start. To the left of the run button, and above the changes column, I see:

> Pending(2)|▼

Both dependent builds finished over an hour before, and there was nothing in the build queue for these two subsequent builds. Refreshing the page also does not help. In the end, I had to launch new builds to clear the pending status. I had a look in the TeamCity [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildCanceling/Stopping) and it seems the only way to clear pending builds is to use the API:

```
curl -v -u user:password --request POST "http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/buildQueue/<buildLocator >" --data "<buildCancelRequest comment='' readdIntoQueue='false' />" --header "Content-Type: application/xml"
```

Is there a UI way to clear pending builds that are not in the build queue?

Comment: The curl command you provided just cancels a build from the build queue which you can perfectly do from UI on the Build Queue page by clicking on "Cancel build" icon for the build.

Answer (score 1):

The `Pending(2)` are in the `changes` column, so there is no item in the build queue with this changes.

This is an indicator to show what changes has not been built on the `default branch`.

Answer (score 1):

Pending(2) indicates that there are two changes committed to your repository that await being built. They might be a result of your other builds, that commits some changes as part of the build process.

I suggest to look closely what files are Pending and what are the changes. It might give you an idea where these changes come from.